# Engine's routes not available in host's views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I got an application that I turned into an engine which has tons of routes. I added the engine to a host app via Gemfile and when I run `rake routes` everything is displayed properly. However, in the views, the routes aren't found resulting in this error:

I access `/` and get following error:

`No route matches {:controller=>"reports" :action=>"new"}`

in file `/Users/username/Sites/engine_app/app/views/home/index.html.erb`:

```
<%= link_to 'New Report', new_report_path %>
```

rake routes:

```
...
reports#new                      new_report GET    /:locale/reports/new(.:format)
...
```

Also, I can access `/en/reports/new` which loads the correct controller and view but get another routing error.

To me, it seems I can access any route directly but the app cannot resolve any xxx_path inside the views at all. Any suggestions?

Comment: at what url you are trying to access new action?

Comment: Anyone else has a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the lack of details in question, I can think only that you are trying to access it from a wrong url. `/:locale/reports/new(.:format)`

you probably open the url without locale:

`localhos:3000/reports/new`

but it should be:

`localhos:3000/en/reports/new`

Comment: I think you got a good point there. What information do you need? I'm kinda stuck here right now.

Comment: first would be, at what url you are trying to access new action?

Comment: "Also, I can access /en/reports/new which loads the correct controller and view but get another routing error." - what error?

Comment: waiting to get the link to start a chat discussion, In chat I can see faster if I can do anything about your problem or not

Comment: here, you can probably join this chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34086/engines-routes-not-available-in-hosts-views